# How to find the URL of the code line from PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

As a developer working in a team, I do the coding in my IDE (PyCharm) but once I want to discuss a line of the code with the team, I go to GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket/etc and find the code I am working on, and click on the left side that the line number of the code is showing and it generate the URL of the code for me. I send the URL to a team member. A sample URL from an open source project is https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/forms.py#L58

The problem is this is a little time consuming, each time I have to find the URL, especially when the project has many levels of directories.

I am wondering, is it there a shortcut/hotkey in PyCharm that I can use to get the URL of the line of code on the remote repository or at least the file I am working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it there a shortcut/hotkey in PyCharm that I can use to get the URL of the line of code on the remote repository or at least the file I am working on?

Please check `Main Menu | Edit | Copy Path/Reference...`

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-code-editor.html#copy_path
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html#copy_options

[image]
*(the pic is from JetBrains PyCharm help page)*

If invoked when a focus is in the Editor on some line *(no repo configured in this test project hence no GitHub option here)*:
[image]

---

If the above does not do what you need, please check **GitLink plugin** then: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8183-gitlink

> A JetBrains plugin providing shortcuts to open or copy a file, directory or commit in GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, Gitee Gitea, Gogs, Azure or Gerrit. Custom hosts can also be configured using the URL template syntax.

Comment: no. none of them has the url of the repo in it

Comment: none of them copies something like this https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/forms.py#L58

Comment: I'm not using that functionality so cannot double check that. Please check GitLink plugin then: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8183-gitlink

Comment: please update your answer to include it

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the line and choose `Open In > Github`.

[image]